Maximizing a Wishart sum
Let $W$ be a $d \times d$ standard Wishart matrix with $n$ degrees of freedom (i.e., $W \sim \mathcal{W}_d(I_d, n)$). Equivalently, $W = \sum_{j=1}^n g_j g_j^T$ where $g_j$ are iid standard multivariate Gaussian vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Define, for a real, symmetric positive definite matrix $X$, the function
$$
f(X) = \sum_{i,j=1}^d \mathbb{E}\Big[(W + X^{-1})^{-1}_{ij}\Big].
$$
Question: Is it possible to determine the maximum
$$
F^\star := \sup_{X \succ 0, \mathrm{tr}(X) \leq 1} f(X) \quad?
$$
Of course, if $d = 1$, we have for $x \in (0, 1]$ that
$$
f(x) = \mathbb{E} \frac{x}{x\sum_{j=1}^n g_j^2 + 1} \leq f(1) = \mathbb{E} \frac{1}{\sum_j g_j^2 + 1} = \mathbb{E}[(\chi^2_n + 1)^{-1}]
$$
Thus, we find $F^\star = \mathbb{E}[1/(\chi^2_n + 1)]$ in this case. However, I am not sure in general (i.e., for $d > 1$) how to proceed.
